# Error: Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with the following code. I keep getting the error message in the title. The code errors out when executing ReportType = ...
I'm rather new to this. Any help is much appreciated.

```
MySQL1 = "SELECT SR.Requestid,RD.rptdesctext as ReportName from SELECTED_REPORT SR inner join REPORT_DESCRIPTION RD on SR.rptdesc = RD.rptdesc where requestid=" & aRequestInfo(nRequest, 1)
                    '---Work with the Record Set
                    rs = New ADODB.Recordset
                    With rs
                        .ActiveConnection = cn
                        .Open(MySQL1)
                        lFoundRequest = (Not (.BOF And .EOF))
                        If lFoundRequest Then
                            '---Initialize Variables
                            GetRequestInfo = True
                            'For nX = 1 To 6
                            '    aRequestReports(nRequest, nX, 6) = "ALL"  '---Service Date Range
                            '    aRequestReports(nRequest, nX, 9) = "ALL"  '---Payment Date Range
                            'Next nX


                            'aRequestInfo(nRequest, 31) = rs.Fields("rptdesctext").Value


                            '---Report Type
                            ReportType = rs.Fields("rptdesctext").Value

                            '---Close Recordset
                            .Close()

                            '---Clear Recordset Variable
                            rs = Nothing
                        End If
                    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using

```
ReportType = rs.Fields("ReportName").Value
```

In your query you are renaming your column `RD.rptdesctext as ReportName` to `ReportName` so you should be using `ReportName` for field name.

Or you can also just omit the renaming of the column `RD.rptdesctext as ReportName` to `RD.rptdesctext` then `ReportType = rs.Fields("rptdesctext").Value` will not be generating any error.